# getting [0, 0] instead of [0, 1] out of my program

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code to get an array and a target number and output the index for the two numbers that will add up to target. for example: `([1, 2, 3], 4) ==> [0, 2]` 
Here's the code:

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for p in range(1, len(numbers)):
            if int(numbers[i]) + int(numbers[p]) == int(target):
                return [numbers.index(numbers[i]), numbers.index(numbers[p])]
```

It's working fine with the example i mentioned and another one. but when it's given the array: 
`([2,2,3], 4)` , instead of `[0, 1]` it's giving me `[0,0]` 
what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

`.index()` returns the *first* instance of a number in a list. At `numbers[1]` you have 2, but the first instance of a 2 is at index 0; hence, `numbers.index(numbers[1])` returns 0.

To resolve your issue, just use `i` and `p` directly (you'll also need to change the indexing for `p`, as for larger lists you can still output the same index twice):

```py
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for p in range(i + 1, len(numbers)):
            if int(numbers[i]) + int(numbers[p]) == int(target):
                return [i, p]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `for p in range(i + 1, len(numbers)):`, i.e. `i + 1` rather than `1`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `i + 1`?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I made a simple change and it works. I do not see the need to complicate the return statment.

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print('this is i', i)
    for p in range(1, len(numbers)):
        print('and this is p', p)
        if int(numbers[i]) + int(numbers[p]) == int(target):
            print('here is p = ', p)
            return [i, p]
```